# Ctrl+Shift+Left or Ctrl+Shift+Right doesn't select words in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

Normally in whatever editor:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd> is used to select the word to the left of cursor
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd> is used to select the word to the right of cursor

Suddenly (after testing many keyboard shortcuts), it stopped working, even in file manager windows, terminals, browsers address bar, etc.

Probably after setting a keyboard shortcut using the combination ctrl+shift+arrow the system shortcut to select text is deleted even after removing the shortcut tested.

For example, lets say my cursor is here:

```
some exampl|e text
```

I want to be able to highlight "exampl" when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd>

But when I press the combination nothing happens.

Where can I change this type of shortcut?
In system keyboard options there is no shortcut for text selection.

Comment: These should work in a text editor or word processor. Please edit you question and add information about which apps have this problem?

Comment: In any editor, even in caja windows, it is certainly a problem in Ubuntu.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem in Ubuntu 20.04 -> gedit and LibreOffice Writer.

Comment: It stopped working, something changed, where can I change this type of shortcut?

Comment: *"Something Changed"* is impossible to troubleshoot. If you can't tell me what changed in your computer, I can't tell you what to do. Nothing changed in my computer. You may want to file a bug report.

Comment: I changed many shortcuts in the system's keyboard options, but I still reviewed all shortcuts to avoid collisions. Where is the ctrl+shift+cursor shortcut defined in the system?

Comment: probably after setting a keyboard shortcut using the combination ctrl+shift+arrow the system shortcut to select text is deleted.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I have the same problem since yesterday. Oddly enough Shift + Ctrl + left (pressed in that order) work but Ctrl + Shift + left don't. It's really annoying!

Comment: I reinstalled my Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem:
Shift + Ctrl + left (pressed in that order) worked but Ctrl + Shift + left didn't.
I can't be sure it's the same as yours with the info you provided. But just in case...

I'm using Gnome and it turns out I enabled the "Locate Pointer" feature (highlighting the pointer's location with left Ctrl, Gnome Settings -> Accessibility -> Pointing & Clicking -> Locate Pointer). Turning it off solved my issue.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem and solved it by restarting my computer.

Now the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow</kbd> keys are working as normal.